# Find the size of S3 folders using PHP SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I am using an S3 bucket but I can't find a way to **retrieve the size of a specific folder inside my bucket**.

Scénario is:

I have a doc for every user on my website `/user1..../user2` where each one will have a limited amount of space (1gb per folder). I need to show on my website the space that they still have like:

```
Canheadd = consumed space (what I'm lookingfor) + new file size
```

to determine if the user still has space or not to them to upload a new file.

I'm aware that you can do a loop of `objectlist` but for me it's not the ideal thing because of the amount and size of each document.

Any new or direct solution is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

There is no 'quick' way to obtain the amount of storage used in a particular 'folder'.

The correct way would be to call `ListObjects(Prefix='folder/',...)`, **iterate through the objects returned** and sum the size of each object. Please note that each call returns a maximum of 1000 objects, so the code might need to make repeated calls to `ListObjects`.

If this method is too slow, you could **maintain a database of all objects and their sizes** and query the database when the app needs to determine the size. Use Amazon S3 Events to trigger an AWS Lambda function when objects are created/deleted to keep the database up-to-date. This is a rather complex method, so I would suggest the first method unless there is a specific reason why it is not feasible.